# Matching drywall to original texture

Tags: drywall, paint

The existing texture is not orange peel, stipple or popcorn. I believe it is roll on texture. I have the mud but do not know what kind of roller or design I need to use to match. Help greatly appreciated.

[image: Paint match]

[image: Paint match 2]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roller that does that usually looks like it has loop carpet on it.

Comment: Do you have a link or an example of what I should look for? roller with "loop carpet" does not turn up anything... =] Thank you, it's appreciated.

Comment: @Firsttimereno just look for a thick knap roller 3/8" to 1/2" deep - your texture is in the paint, not the mud.

Comment: I mean, there are specific buckets of texture that are premixed mud. The texture is in the mud depending on how you paint it. The paint is just the final layer that goes on uniformly throughout....

Answer (score 0):

This loop carpet texture seems to be more dotty as opposed to flowing waves ... https://www.homedepot.com/p/Linzer-9-in-x-1-4-in-Carpet-Texture-Stippler-Roller-Cover-RC-115/203713306